# C++ map adds new element

Tags: c++, linux

I have a basic query in the C++ maps,

```
map<char,string> mymap;

  mymap['a']="an element";
  mymap['b']="another element";
  mymap['c']=mymap['b'];

  cout << "mymap['a'] is " << mymap['a'] << endl;
  cout << "mymap['b'] is " << mymap['b'] << endl;
  cout << "mymap['c'] is " << mymap['c'] << endl;
  cout << "mymap['d'] is " << mymap['d'] << endl;
```

when we try to access mymap['d'], I get a default value because operator inserts a new element in the map with that key and initialized to its default value,  even though it is accessed only to retrieve its value. Next time when I use the iterator, I could see the null value for the key 'd'. Is there any way to restrict the map inserting default values.

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen when you write `mymap['d']`?

Comment: If you took that code verbatim from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/, it would have been polite to mention it. Especially since that page poses and answers your question. "
Notice how the last access (to element 'd') inserts a new element in the map with that key and initialized to its default value (an empty string) even though it is accessed only to retrieve its value. Member function map::find does not produce this effect."

Answer (score 8):

You should use `map.find` instead of `operator []` if you do not want default insertion.

[map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/)

```
iterator find ( const key_type& x );
const_iterator find ( const key_type& x ) const;
```

Searches the container for an element with x as key and returns an iterator to it if found, otherwise it **returns an iterator to map::end** (the element past the end of the container)

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected and documented behaviour of `std::map`. In order to check the existence of some item, use [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/).

Answer (score 1):

Use map's member function `iterator find(const key_type& k)` for query only.
map's operator[] has some 'special effect'

```
data_type& operator[](const key_type& k)
```

Returns a reference to the object that is associated with a particular key. If the map does not already contain such an object, operator[] inserts the default object data_type(). [3]

More reference can be found at
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

```
map<char, string>::iterator mIte = mymap.find('d');
if(mIte != mymap.end())
cout << "mymap['d'] is " << mIte->second << endl;
else
cout << "mymap['d'] is empty" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only is this the documented behavior, but with a little thought it's easy to see why. There are only two sensible outcomes to an index operation: either return a valid entry in the map, or throw an exception. If you don't throw the exception then the only choice is to create a new entry. I don't know why the standard chose one over the other, but that's the way it is.

Microsoft provides an `at` method that throws instead of creating the element, but this does not appear to be in the standard or in [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01094.html).

It's easy to create a function that uses `find` to do the same thing:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
Value& at(std::map<Key,Value> & the_map, const Key & the_key)
{
    std::map<Key,Value>::iterator it = the_map.find(the_key);
    if (it == the_map.end())
        throw std::out_of_range("map index invalid");
    return it->second;
}

template<typename Key, typename Value>
const Value& at(const std::map<Key,Value> & the_map, const Key & the_key)
{
    std::map<Key,Value>::const_iterator it = the_map.find(thekey);
    if (it == the_map.end())
        throw std::out_of_range("map index invalid");
    return it->second;
}
```

Comment: `map::at` is defined in C++11, which GCC only supports in recent versions, and if you ask for it (with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`).

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` will always insert a default value if the key is not already in the map.

In C++11, `mymap.at('d')` will throw `out_of_range`, and not insert a default value.

In C++03, you can emulate it with `find`:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename C, typename A>
Value at(std::map<Key,Value,C,A> const & map, Key const & key)
{
    typename std::map<Key,Value,C,A>::const_iterator found = map.find(key);
    if (found == map.end()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("at(map,key)");
    }
    return found->second;
}
```